# How to iterate over elements in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Actually i want to read emails one by one in junk folder of "outlook:live" and mark emails "Not spam".[image: emails selected with xpath]

emails = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class = 'xoCOIP8PzdTVy0T6q_uG6']")))

This xpath matches 400 instances. I want to make a loop to select one email at a time like select first email, click on the div and perform action and then 2nd email and so on. I'm trying this

```
 emails = WebDriverWait(driver, 
 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class = 
 'xoCOIP8PzdTVy0T6q_uG6']")))

 for count in range(0,len(emails)):
    (emails)[count+1].click()
```

Please help me know where im doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: What programming language is this?  You should probably add whatever language it is as a tag.

Comment: Have you considered the API? Are you doing this for fun or ? You know you can select all and mark them whatever you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the function you're using to return the clickable elements is only returning a single element, so you'll have to use a different function, make a change in your logic, etc.

For instance, you could use Selenium's `find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'xoCOIP8PzdTVy0T6q_uG6']")` which will return a list of WebElement object(s) if the element(s) are found, or an empty list if the element(s) is not found. This will, of course, not take into consideration the possibility of the elements not being completely loaded on the page. In my experience, just slapping a `time.sleep(10)` after you open the page is "'good enough".

I recommend making sure your elements can be discovered and interacted with first to make sure this isn't all in vain, if you haven't already.

---

Another option is to add another function, something like a  `elements_to_be_clickable()` function, to the Expected Conditions source code.

From the Expected Condition [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html), I've done some research and it looks like the `element_to_be_clickable()` function only returns a single element. Moreover, from the [source code](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#element_to_be_clickable), said function mainly makes use of the `visibility_of_element_located()` function. I believe you could follow similar logic to the `element_to_be_clickable()` function, but instead use the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` function, in order to return multiple WebElements (since `visibiilty_of_all_elements_located()` returns a list of WebElements).